# How to make a self-signed certificate trusted?

Tags: windows, windows-10, security, ssl, certificate

I've created a self signed certificate on my Windows 10 PC and would like to see it trusted by the web browsers on the same machine.

To do this, I've added the certificate to the 'Trusted Root Certification Authorities' section of the Windows Certificate Manager. (To open certificate manager, use Windows + R, type certmgr.msc)

But even after this, Internet Explorer 11 and Microsoft Edge show certificate errors.

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is the certificate error that you are seeing? There are many reasons why a browser would display a warning about a certificate other than trust issues.

Comment: @MarkoPolo True, turns out the certificate error was 'Mismatched Address'. The certificate was issued for <machinename>.<domain>.com and I was opening the site using only <machinename>.com. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the Certificate Error in the browser, inspite of adding the certificate to the 'Trusted Root Certification Authorities' is because the certificate was issued for `<machinename>.<domain>.com`. I was opening the site using just `<machinename>`.

When opening the sites using `<machinename>.<domain>.com`, no certificate errors are shown in any browser.

The certificate error I had received was 'Mismatched Address'.